# ¿Cómo puedo convertir elementos de una lista a float?

Tags: python

Poseo una lista con los siguientes valores:

```
(('1', '2', '2', '2'), 'int')
(('4.0', '2.0', '2.5', '2.5'), 'float')
(('?', '3.0', '2.5', '2.5'), 'float')
(('?', '?', '?', '?'), None)
(('none', 'none', 'tc', 'tc'), 'string')
(('?', '?', '?', '39'), 'int')
```

Donde en la primera de las sublistas, se me indica los datos a tratar y donde en la segunda el tipo de dato que es.

Dependiendo del tipo de dato que es tengo que calcular una cosa u otra. Por ejemplo, si es de tipo 'int' o 'float' debería calcular la media de esos valores, si es de tipo 'string' la moda (palabra más repetida) y si es '?', no realizar nada.

Los datos de mi lista son evaluados como 'string', es por ello que necesito conversiones dependiendo del tipo de dato que estoy utilizando.

Esta es la función que estoy realizando:

```
def promedio (lista):  
    for a in lista:
        suma = 0
        if a[-1] == "int":
          for elementos in a[0]:
             sumar = suma + float(elementos)
          print sumar/len(a[0]
          #conversor a float
        elif a[-1] == "float":
          #print "hola float"
        elif a[-1] == "string":
          #print "hola string"
        else:
          #print "?"
```

Como podéis observar, comparo el elemento de mi lista a[-1] que me devuelve el tipo de esos datos , para el caso primer devolvería 'int', para posteriormente aplicar un opción u otra.

En el caso de int, recorro los elementos que tengo en mi sub lista dentro de mi lista 'a', e intento aplicar un conversor para pasar de string a float para realizar la operación aritmética correspondiente.

Sin embargo he probado de distintas formas y siempre me sale el siguiente error:

> ```
> Could not convert string to float:
> ```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Fíjate que el error te salta cuando lee la última línea: `(('?', '?', '?', '39'), 'int')`. Al ver que es de tipo `int`, intenta hacer `for elementos in a[0]` y, por tanto, `float(elementos)`. Como elementos vale `?`, protesta.

Comment: la entrada de tu función es un tupla como la que muestras ?  `(('1', '2', '2', '2'), 'int')`

Comment: Por cierto, indicas _si es '?', no realizar nada_. Sin embargo, de ese tipo no hay ninguno pero sí de tipo None. ¿Podrías revisar el ejemplo y el enunciado? ¿Y qué dice el algoritmo respecto qué hacer con valores que son "?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que no te mande el error deberas condicionar o capturar con un `try`

```
def promedio (lista):  
    for a in lista:
        suma = 0
        if a[-1] == "int":
          if not "?" in a[0]: # si no hay ningún caracter "?"
             for elementos in a[0]:
                sumar = suma + float(elementos)
             print sumar/len(a[0]
          else:
             print("no se puede procesar")
          #conversor a float
        elif a[-1] == "float":
          #print "hola float"
        elif a[-1] == "string":
          #print "hola string"
        else:
          #print "?"
```

Depende de lo que necesites puedes completar tu código. pero el error es ese que no podrás convertir el carácter `"?"` en `float` ni en `int`

Saludos

Comment: Correcto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas una condición adicional para pasar por alto las `?`. Añade la siguiente línea dentro de tu loop `for elementos in a[0]:`.

```
if elementos != "?":
```

El error te salta al intentar convertir en float el carácter `?`.